# How to register an x86 DLL on Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: dll, 64-bit, 32-bit, syswow64

I have 32bit dll files and I need to register them on windows 7 x64,
I have tries the regsvr.exe file that exists in the folder c:\windows\syswow64
However, nothing happened with me, and I haven't got a successful message.

When I searched for my dlls in regedt , I haven't found it.

So, how can I solve that.

Regards,
Aya.

Answer (score 0):

It's no different to doing it on 32-bit Windows.

It also doesn't matter which of the two regsvr32.exe versions you run: The 32-bit one is clever enough to call the 64-bit one if a 64-bit DLL is passed to it, and vice versa. (At least on Windows 7.)

If you're getting an error or the registration request doesn't return at all then the problem is likely to be with the registration function in the DLL (e.g. it's getting stuck in a long or endless operation or loop due to some other platform difference), or the DLL itself (e.g. some of its dependencies are missing).